# How to specify a flex item to be of certain minimum width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to use `display: flex`, but some `inline-block`s should never be shrunk. I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Here's a repro of my situation:

```css
.marker {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #cef;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;">
  <p>The blue boxes should be 2em wide!</p>
  <label>
    <span class="marker"></span>
    <span class="text">Some rather long text which is the whole reason for using flexbox.</span>    
  </label> 
  <label>
    <span class="marker"></span>
    <span class="text">Short text.</span>    
  </label> 
</div>
```

The problem is that `.marker` is not of specified `width: 2em`, but instead is rather narrow.

I've read through [css-tricks' helpful Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). The only property that seemed useful was `flex-shrink` (I was expecting something of a "never shrink" property), but found no way to use it for my purpose. I've skimmed [the MDN flex pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) but couldn't find a solution there either. Lastly, I've also carefully reviewed the "duplicate" suggestions Stack Overflow gave me when I wrote this question, but no solution there either.

How can you specify a flex item to never shrink beyond a certain minimum width?

Comment: I don't know is this the right way or not...or it is applicable to you or not..but just a suggestion    when we put the .marker width to min-width it works and also if we put the position absolute then it also works...if i am advising wrong i appologise

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and the [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) properties.

> The CSS flex-basis property specifies the flex basis which is the
>   initial main size of a flex item. The property determines the size of
>   the content-box unless specified otherwise using box-sizing.

Change your `.marker` as follows:

```css
.marker {
  flex: 0 0 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #cef;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;">
  <p>The blue box should be 2em wide!</p>
  <label>
    <span class="marker"></span>
    <span class="text">Some rather long text which is the whole reason for using flexbox.</span>    
  </label>  
</div>
```

Alternatively you could continue using `width: 2em` and use just this flex-shorthand:

```
.marker
{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

The problems you are experiencing are caused by the default values of the `flex` property. Each child of a flex-container is becoming a flex item with: `flex-grow:1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%;` ([See here for more info](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)).

This properties allows your flex item to shrink, which is not wanted in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the question I posed! I do realize now I simplified a bit too much in my question: if there's a second `label` with a very short text the `.marker` will go *beyond* `2em`. Any comment on that? (Or shall I prevent this becoming a "chameleon question" and post a new one?)

Comment: PS. I've updated my question with the additional situation (short text), but if you feel that was too radical feel free to rollback my edit. (In that case I'll accept your answer and ask a follow-up question.) And in either case: many thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @Jeroen thank you for the update. Now i'am a bit confused, what is your actual problem. Here is a jsFiddle with small modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/u8nerkxu/ but this is using a fixed-width on `.marker`. Maybe you can demonstrate your problem and maybe show, what you want to achieve

Comment: It all makes sense now! The `flex: 0 0 auto;` was exactly what I needed. In hindsight I feel I should've been able to deduce that from your answer. Thanks a bunch. (PS. A minor detail, but with the last edit to my question I'd suggest changing your Stack Snippet to `0 0 auto` too.)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the wrap code on your display flex:

```
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
```

Otherwise the min-width:xxx woun't have effect.